# gnuplot single title in loop structure

Tags: loops, plot, gnuplot

How can you assign only one title to a line when you also use a for loop?

I have the follwoing command line:

```
plot for [i=1:15] "test.txt" using (i-1):i title "test" lc rgb "red" ps 0.4 lw 0.5
```

But the title is of course repeated 15 times. I would like the title to appear only for one time. Is there a way to avoid this without using label? I have searched but nothing looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty titles are omitted. Simply check variable `i`:

```
plot for [i=1:15] "test.txt" using (i-1):i title (i == 1 ? "test" : "")
```